# Manual Test Script Templates

Tags: manual-testing

Can anyone post good test script templates(MSExcel)?
-- For Software Testing Project
thanks

Comment: Software Testing --> Need a good templates(in Excel) to write manual test cases for Functionality Testing and End to End Testing.

Answer (score 4):

1. Test Case ID - An unique ID to identify the test case
2. Precondition - Specify any precondition required to start the test case
3. Test Case Description - A Brief description explaining the purpose of the test case or the feature that is under test
4. Test Steps - Explain in detail all the necessary test steps required to be done to execute the test case
5. Expected Behavior - Clearly mention what is the expected behavior captured in the requirements
6. Author - Name of the test case owner
7. Requirement Origin - Feature name
8. Result - Pass / Fail / Not Run
9. Bug / Defect ID - To map the failed test cases
10. Remarks - Any comments

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1.Level 
2.FD Reference
3.Requirement ID
4.Test Type 
5.Test Case Name
6.Test Case Number
7.Action
8.Expected Result
9.Outcome
10.Comments 
11.Application
12.Release Scope
13.Critical

Answer (score 1):

Test Case Id    :Serial no assigned to test case

Purpose         :Brief idea about case

Test Created By :Name of test creator

Test Environment:   Software or hardware in which the test case is executed

Prerequisites   :Conditions that should be fulfilled before the test is performed

Test Procedure  :Steps to be performed in test

Test Data   :Inputs, variables and data

Expected Result :LWhat the program should do

Actual Result   :What is actually done

Verdict         : Pass/Fail(Status of the test)

Comments    :Notes on the procedure

Answer (score 0):

[image: test template]

This file might help you.. This is the template for functionality testing